# iOS CoreBluetooth CBPeripheral didReceiveReadRequest

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have two projects. One acts as central ,the other as a peripheral. Central has connected to peripheral, then central calls method `readValueForCharacteristic`.
Not immediately, but after about 5-10 seconds, peripheral invokes delegate method `- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request`. Why is there a delay? How can I eliminate the delay?
 Any thoughts? I've been trying for almost a week now.
 Appreciate every helps, thanks

### central

```
- (void)sendBtnClick:(id)sender
{
    USCPeerBtn *btn = (USCPeerBtn *)sender;
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = btn.connectedPeripheral;
    if (!peripheral) {
        return;
    }

    [self.charachterMDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        if (key == peripheral) {
            [(CBPeripheral *)key readValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)obj]; // read
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

### periperal

```
// CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral  didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveReadRequest");
}
```

Comment: Your central and peripheral apps running on same device or different?

Comment: Why are you using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` when you could just say `CBCharacteristic *char=(CBCharacteristic *)self.charachterMDict[peripheral];` ?  Presumably you call `respondToRequest:` but haven't shown this?

Comment: I haven't call  `respondToRequest:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `respondToRequest:` in method `- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral  didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request`

```
// CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral     didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request
{
    [peripheral respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveReadRequest");
}
```

@Paulw11 ,thanks